# Unable to remove shadow from the Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am trying to remove shadow from the navigationbar but not get success (iOS7).

Used the code below,

**Method 1**

```
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:image
       forBarPosition:UIBarPositionAny
       barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setShadowImage:[UIImage new]];
```

**Method 2**

```
    for (UIView *view in self.navigationController.navigationBar.subviews) {
        for (UIView *view2 in view.subviews) {
            if ([view2 isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
                [view2 removeFromSuperview];
            }
        }
    }
```

**Method 3**

```
    [self.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
```

**Method 4**

```
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setShadowImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc] init] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

**Method 5**

```
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:image
                                                 forBarPosition:UIBarPositionAny
                                                     barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setShadowImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"transparentpx.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(1, 1, 1, 1)]];
```

None of them worked for me.
Could any one suggest new method..

Answer (score 1):

Using an empty image hasn't worked for me.

I had to use a 1x1 pixel transparent image as the shadow image in order for it to appear invisible.

```
[self.navigationBar setShadowImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar-shadow"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(1, 1, 1, 1)]];
```

Comment: Yes Tried that also didn't work for me. Added it in method 1.

Comment: No, in *method 1* you use `[UIImage new]` which is an image object without any image data - my method uses an image with transparent image data - there is a difference. I also think the resizableImage makes a difference too.

Comment: Out of interest - try the transparent shadow image method without setting a background image for the nav bar itself.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer.opacity = 0;
self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer.borderWidth = 0;
self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
```